# Full path of the file from the remote server

Tags: c#, .net, file, mapped-drive, httppostedfilebase

I am working with files and I don't really understand how to make it work.

I have a web application (c#) that is located on the server and users use this application to upload some information from the files. The problem that I am having that users upload the file (using `HttpPostedFileBase` class) from their local machines but code is trying to match the same path on the server and of course the file doesn't exist on the server, that's why it throws an error saying that

> Cannot find a part of the path ...

If the user is trying to upload the file from `C:\Users\User1\Documents\File.txt` from their local machine how can I write the code to include the whole path to the file including the computer name and the local drive something like `\\ComputerName\c$\Users\User1\Documnets\File.txt`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but... why do you need the user's local path to the file at all?  You've already stated that the file is being uploaded, so what does the original path of the file matter since it is now stored on the server?

Comment: You should refer to either FTP, or HTTP file upload protocol if you are using Web Page on client's machine. Best regards,

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I am not uploading the file. I am trying to save the file to the server. If my drive is correctly mapped, I dont have any problems, but to save the file I need to know the place that I am copying it from and the place where I am copying to. In this case because it's a client's machine I dont see the full path to the file to successfully upload it.

Comment: So `\\ComputerName\c$` is actually on the server? Or is it on the client?

Comment: Patrick, I want to access \\ComputerName\c$ from my server, so in this case ComputerName should be the client's machine

Comment: @MarinaS: Then I did get your question correctly. My answer answers that: not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Client and servers are disconnected from each other. That is how the web works. You can't get the full client path and access that in any way from the server.

There are very good reasons for this, the most important one is security / trust.

Comment: How can I save the file from the client's machine to the server than without knowing the full path?

Comment: You have to save it somewhere on the server, depending on your needs. The easiest way it to create a file path yourself, and then save it using [`HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I am trying the exact the same thing:
var fileLocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), string.Join(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), files.FileName));
files.SaveAs(fileLocation);

But it fails to save it saying that the part of the path is not found

Comment: Also note that the first parameter of `string.Join` is the separator.

Comment: fileLocation usually is something like C:\Users\UserName\Documents\FileName

Comment: This is in the error message - C:\Users\UserName\Docuemnts\FileName

Comment: @MarinaS: Is that all?

Comment: I am running my code locally and trying to upload the file from our  server: 
my fileLocation is "C:\\Users\\MarinaS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Install Guide.docx", I can see I can save it in that directory without any problems. But if I do it on the server it throws an error...

Comment: You mean in iis? Does the iis user have a temp directory? Or a user directory at all?

Comment: There is no temp directory, but there is a user directory.

Comment: I guess that is the problem. Try create it or write to another folder.

Comment: I've tested and the Temp folder was hidden, so it's actually there. I really dont know why it's not working how it should.

Comment: Try go change the path to somewhere inside the wen site folder to check if it is an file access issue.

Comment: I've tried in our live environment and it works fine without changing the path. Looks like it was fixed by itself really...

Comment: Okay. Glad you fixed it!

Comment: Argh! Was hoping for a solution. Weird thing is that it "cannot find a part of the path...<*source* path>", not destination.