# How can I pass a full file path from the client to the MVC controller?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass the selected file path to the controller. Here is a part of my form:

```
    <input type="file" name="sourceFile" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
```

And here is my action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase sourceFile)
    {
        string path = Path.GetFullPath(sourceFile.FileName);
        ...            
        return View();
    }
```

But instead of the real path, I get `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\myFile.csv`.
But the file does not exist there. All I need is to copy the file from one location to another.

Comment: No, someone else just asked this same question.  That is a browser limitation and a security feature.  You, as a web server, do not need to know a user's file system.  You only need the file that they have chosen to give you.

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to make this an answer, so that I could mark it accordingly?

Comment: Why do you want to know the file path on the client machine?

Comment: I need to copy a file from one location to another, so I need to be able to find it.

Comment: ***[Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693031/unable-to-get-the-folder-location-in-test-server-in-asp-net-mvc) was asked a couple of hours ago.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sourceFile` contains the file **on your server** once it is uploaded. You need to call `sourceFile.SaveAs` to save the file to a path on your server that you specify.

There is no good reason for the server to know where the file is stored on the client's file system. All the app should care about is the actual file once it is uploaded.

Comment: I tried to use it, but the file was not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express... Can you tell why?

Comment: That file doesn't exist in that place.

Comment: I see... SaveAs does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That file path doesn't actually exist. The reason you think it is is because you don't understand what the `Path.GetFullPath` does. For a relative path, it adds the current working directory. That's all. It doesn't really save it somewhere or checks it exists.

The actual file path is something you create. You can use the file path give from the client as a start, but you will have to create a place on the server to save it there. You use the data passed in the `HttpPostedFileBase` and save it somewhere.

Also see my answer on the question [Full path of the file from the remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609849/full-path-of-the-file-from-the-remote-server/27609891#27609891) that cover some other aspects of your question.